# Removendo replaceAll("[().-\"]")

Tags: java, string, regex

Estou usando o `openJDK1.7`, estou precisando de ajuda.

```
String[] vetor = {"\"Jui.ce \"", "j-90.0", "Abobr.e-u"};

for(int = 0; i < vetor.length; i++)
   vetor[i].replaceAll("[()-.\"]", "");
```

O código acima entre outros não está dando problema mas não esta funcionando, quando aplico para remover um por vez da certo. Queria remover de uma vez só. Onde estou errando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe `String` em Java é imutável. Isso significa que seu valor não muda depois de sua criação. Quando você chama o método `replaceAll(String regex, String replacement)`, uma nova `String` é retornada com o resultado e a `String` original permanece inalterada. Tente dessa forma:

```
String[] vetor = {"\"Jui.ce \"", "j-90.0", "Abobr.e-u"};
String[] resultado = new String[vetor.length];

for(int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++)
   resultado[i] = vetor[i].replaceAll("[()-.\"]", "");

for(String s : resultado)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: Boa Noite, Felipe! Obrigado... funcionou
https://goo.gl/oVez3R IDE Online só para compartilhar o funcionamento.

Comment: boa (+1). Um pequeno detalhe: o caracter `-` em conjuntos de caracteres precisa de ser protegido: `[)-.]` = `[)*+,-]`

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma

- "quando aplico para remover um por vez da certo", pegue e monte isso, da seguinte forma:
- [ "valor-1"|"valor-2"|"valor-3"] teste e veja se da certo.
- Detalhe isso pode ser bem mais lento do que remover **um por um**
- Posta o resultado ai, não consegui testar aqui isso.

Puxa assim não, tem erro de programação, não de analise de expressão regular.

```
public class ManipulandoString{
  public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] vetor = {"\"Jui.ce \"", "j-90.0", "Abobr.e-u"};
        String[] result = new String[3];
        for(int i=0; i <vetor.length; i++)
            result[i]=vetor[i].replaceAll("[.|\"|\\(|\\)|-]", "");
        for(int i = 0; i < vetor.length; i++)
         System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
```

}

> veja o resultado isso, tentei atualizar no teste, acho que esta lá, se não é só copiar daqui pra lá.

Comment: Marcelo, Boa Noite!

for(int i =0; i < vetor.length; i++)
           vetor[i].replaceAll("\"|\\(|\\)|-|.", "");

Rodou só que não mudou nada, o hífen e parenteses e os demais continuam no mesmo lugar, vou colocar em uma IDE online

Comment: https://goo.gl/t0fXuW
Conforme o prometido rodando mas não altera, vou tentar a dica do Felipe Marinho

Comment: Veja atualizei a reposta